# throw new Error(INPUT_ERROR); Error: input is invalid type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

here is my redux store code it gives the input type error or input invalid error
but this error is coming in development mode not on production why it is so, i don't have any clue

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import sessionStorage from "redux-persist/lib/storage/session";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { createStateSyncMiddleware } from "redux-state-sync";

const SET_CLIENT_STATE = "SET_CLIENT_STATE";
const middlewares = [
thunk,
createStateSyncMiddleware({
    // blacklist: ["extras", "products"]
    whitelist: ["user"],
}),
];

const persistConfig = {
key: "root",
storage,
whitelist: ["user", "loggedInDoctor", "loggedInPatient"],
};

const sessionRedConfig = {
key: "referrer",
storage: sessionStorage,
};

const { referrer, ...otherReducer } = rootReducer;

const allReducers = combineReducers({
...otherReducer,
referrer: persistReducer(sessionRedConfig, referrer),
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, allReducers);

const makeConfiguredStore = (reducer, initialState) =>
createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);

export const makeStore = (initialState, { isServer, req, debug, storeKey }) => {
if (isServer) {
    initialState = initialState || { fromServer: "foo" };
    return makeConfiguredStore(allReducers, initialState);
} else {
    // we need it only on client side
    const store = makeConfiguredStore(persistedReducer, initialState);
    store.__persistor = persistStore(store); // Nasty hack
    return {
    ...store,
    store,
    };
}
};

export const setClientState = (clientState) => ({
type: SET_CLIENT_STATE,
payload: clientState,
});
```